# J2ME Location API on the N95 - Need to open Nokia Maps to warm up GPS?

Tags: java-me, geolocation, gps, n95

The location API only seems to work for me when I warm up the GPS by opening Nokia Maps or Google Maps.

The Google Maps app has a status balloon which shows the number of satellites and lets the user know when the connection is active, however I have not found anything in the J2ME Location API docs which specifies how to do this.

It seems like these apps are calling some function which kick-starts the GPS. Without opening them the Location API will just time out in my app.

Answer (score 1):

Use LocationListener ... :)

Comment: I use LocationListener too, and didn't get this problem